# Identify the pins of the circuitry that resides within a laptop battery

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, batteries, laptop

My ASUS laptop battery stopped working all of a sudden, when it had no reason to (new). Windows says "Plugged in, charging" , but the battery always stuck at 0%.

Before getting a replacement battery, I decided to investigate a little bit and opened up the battery case(A41-X550A external, detachable). It's just four 18650 cells connected in series with a PCB consisting of a few ICs, an NTC thermistor and a connector that goes to the laptop. I checked the voltage of each cell and found them to be around 3.7 Volt, which makes sense as the battery is rated for 15 V, 2950 mAh.

However, despite the battery providing 15 Volts at the end terminals of the 4 cells in series, I am getting no output (0 Volts) from the positive out of the connector which is a part of the PCB. There are 5 other pins on the connector (ID, D, C, SYS, NC). Apart from the Not Connected pin, I am not sure what the others mean or stand for. I am convinced that I will need to operate on one of these pins to "switch on" the connection between the battery out and the 15 V from the series cells.

Pictures have been attached and it would be extremely helpful if someone could identify the pins and also maybe a possible fix to the whole conundrum.

P.S- I tried shorting the 15 Volts and the battery out and connected it to the laptop. Nothing new. Plugged in, charging and 0%.
I also got a battery of the same model from a friend who had the same problem. Opened it up and again, all the cells are healthy with no output at the battery out pin.

[image: pinout]

Comment: This is a repair question, which is off-topic for this site. We would need a schematic of the supply and be able to test it ourselves, which is not possible.

Comment: ID, D, and C are probably Identify, Data, and Clock. Not that that helps you…

Comment: @Adarsh: A tip for your posts: 2 x <Enter> for paragraph breaks.

Comment: @duskwuff Maybe it could. Do you think you could give one line explanations of what those pins are for?      Especially the ID pin. I could find out about D and C using Google.

Comment: @AdarshPryce Not in any great detail. D/C might be I²C, ID could be anything really.

Comment: found this ... it may provide some info ... http://kuzyatech.com/testing-laptop-battery-pinout-smbus-charge-capacity .... there is a mention of a resistor to enable the output

Comment: @jsotola Thanks a lot. That link seems promising and could possibly help me start up the battery. I shall go through it in detail and see what I can make out of it.

Answer (score 2):

> It's just four 18650 cells connected in series with a PCB consisting
>   of a few ICs

Yes, the problem is likely in those just little few ICs and/or power switches. Laptop battery is a fairly sophisticated charging and cell-balancing system, with a bunch of protective and service circuitry, including charge monitor, all based on embedded microprocessors. It is called "smart battery". If the battery communication with host was successful, it means that some power element/fuse/MOSFET has died/fried/burned.

For ASUS-made battery (as well as for the vast majority of them, including Dell/HP etc.), the components are Taiwan/China/Japan sourced, an it is practically impossible to find replacement components, and if the MCU controller has died, then it is a dead end. If you are extremely curious, you should reverse engineer the PCB schematics and post it here, maybe then people can give you some practical advice.

Comment: That seems like a start. I will get started on deducing the circuit diagram from the PCB. I have already ordered a replacement battery and this is more to me about understanding what really goes inside.